# Retrieving 2 rows from one SELECT sql query with 2 tables PHP

Tags: php, sql, select, union

```
QUOTES TABLE
-----------------
QUOTE_ID_PK  PICKUP_FROM_ID  DROPOFF_TO_ID
1               4                     3
2               2                     3
3               1                     1
4               1                     2
5               3                     2


TOWN TABLE
---------------
 TOWN_ID_PK  DISTANCE    NAME
    1        34          South Central 
    2        43          airport
    3        99          bus station
    4        66          train station
```

I have 2 tables to work out a simple distance formula.

I need to return 2 rows (with the value of distance) for  ORDER_ID in the orders table.

I get results of  order_id =2 , pickupfromdistance=43, dropoffto=99.

I have tried a few ideas from this site, and here is what I have that almost works, but doesn't return the second distance value. Have I gone about this the wrong way? Am I making a complex solution to a simple problem?

```
SELECT town.town_id_pk AS townID, town.distance AS distance, town.name AS townName, town.location AS location, quotes.pickupfrom_id, quotes.dropoffto_id 
FROM town, quotes 
WHERE quotes.pickupfrom_id=town.town_id_pk 
AND quotes.quote_id_pk = '140419420'
UNION ALL
SELECT town.town_id_pk AS townID, town.distance AS distance, town.name AS townName, town.location AS location, quotes.pickupfrom_id, quotes.dropoffto_id
FROM town, quotes 
WHERE quotes.dropoffto_id=town.town_id_pk 
AND quotes.quote_id_pk = '140419420'";
```

E.G.
I am selecting:

```
QUOTE_ID_PK=2, wh
```

(which has PICKUP_FROM_ID=2, and DROPOFF_TO_ID=3)

The result I'm after would be something like this:

```
TOWN_ID_PK=2, DISTANCE=43, NAME=AIRPORT
```

then the next ROW would be

```
TOWN_ID_PK=3, DISTANCE=99, NAME= BUS STATION
```

Once I know which distance is further, I can then continue on with the code to work out rate per klm etc (I can work this part out myself).

Comment: 1) Learn to use JOINs 2) Your distances only have any meaning if pickup and dropoff are exactly opposite each other from your base point

Comment: quote_id_pk is not listed in the quotes table. Could you please list the complete structure (or at least all the relevant columns) of the table?

Comment: wow, thanks for the fast response guys. the actual tables have a lot more info than the sample ones i made up above. And yes Mark I understand what you mean. I have one town as a "basetown" and then the other towns as "distance from base"... so when the user enters a search to go from TOWN A to TOWN B, the sql will look up on the database to check that either town is a BASETOWN and then work out the distance and cost from there, based on the longest distance

Comment: fixed up the table above showing quote_id_pk joseph.

Comment: Your original UNION ALL method seems to work fine. See this fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8dbd3/4 Please make sure that quote_id_pk is varchar (since you have enclosed 140419420 in single quotes).

Answer (score 0):

Just to give a hint:

```
SELECT 
  ORDER_ID, 
  PICKUP_FROM_TOWN_ID, 
  (SELECT DISTANCE FROM TOWN  where TOWN_ID_PK = quotes.DROPOFF_TO_ID) as DISTANCE, 
  quotes.DROPOFF_TO_ID  
from town, quotes 
WHERE quotes.PICKUP_FROM_TOWN_ID=town.TOWN_ID_PK
AND ORDER_ID = '140419420'
```

and here's an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e734918/1)

**Edited:**

in order to get two rows, just try this:

```
SELECT 
  ORDER_ID, 
  PICKUP_FROM_TOWN_ID, 
  DISTANCE,
  DROPOFF_TO_ID  
from town, quotes 
WHERE 
    ( quotes.PICKUP_FROM_TOWN_ID=town.TOWN_ID_PK or quotes.DROPOFF_TO_ID=town.TOWN_ID_PK )
AND ORDER_ID = 2
```

new [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e734918/5/0)

Comment: ideally i would like to see another row in the results showing ORDERID=4, DROPOFF_TO_ID=2 and DISTANCE=43

Comment: thanks again axel, one more question, how do i distingish the differnece between the "distance" returned? eg DISTANCE A= 43, AND DISTANCE B= 99

Comment: Array ( [quote_id_pk] => 140419432 [pickupfrom_id] => 3 [distance] => 1 [dropoffto_id] => 12 )     Array ( [quote_id_pk] => 140419432 [pickupfrom_id] => 3 [distance] => 127 [dropoffto_id] => 12 ) This is the result I am getting from my database using Axel's answer, which is working, But how to I set a $distance1 and $distance2 to the two distance results?

Comment: It's not very clear waht you are trying to achieve. For instance, the "dropoff city" has a "distance" of 43 - to what ?? See above comments to that. Ideally, you need a table which lists all iterations of dropoff and pickup with just one distance

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to get the distance for the two towns?  If so, you would do this with `join`:

```
select oq.*, tfrom.distance as distance_from, tto.distance as to_distance
from OrderQuotes oq left outer join
     Towns tfrom
     on oq.PICKUP_FROM_TOWN_ID = tfrom.town_id_pk left outer join
     Towns tto
     on oq.PICKUP_TO_TOWN_ID = tto.town_id_pk;
```

Comment: trying to get both distances for the two towns, then work out which one is furtherest away to do a rate per kilometre

Comment: @user3556674 . . . That seems rather far removed from the question as originally described.  I would suggest that you delete this question and ask another question.  Include sample data, the results that you want, and an explanation of the real problem.  Just modifying this question is unfair to the people who have already attempted to answer it.

Comment: sorry gordon, this is the first time ive used stackoverflow to ask a question. i have updated the question with what I am trying to do. E.G I am selecting QUOTE_ID_PK=2, wh (which has PICKUP_FROM_ID=2, and DROPOFF_TO_ID=3)

The result im after would be something like this: TOWN_ID_PK=2, DISTANCE=43, NAME=AIRPORT then the next ROW would be TOWN_ID_PK=3, DISTANCE=99, NAME= BUS STATION